# Total Paid amount mismatch in magento having Total Due £0.01

Tags: php, magento

I am using this extension to give 5% discount for all newsletter subscribed customers, its working fine but the only bug i got is when i look the order in magento backend it says Total Due £0.01 and also in World pay transaction history it says total order amount £5.43

Subtotal    £2.85
Shipping & Handling £2.59
Discount (5% Discounted Subtotal)   £2.71
Tax £0.14
Grand Total £5.44
Total Paid  £5.43
Total Refunded  £0.00
Total Due   £0.01

Below is the code for the extension i am using:

```
<?php

class Sugarcode_Customdiscount_Model_Observer
{
    public function setDiscount($observer)
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["subscribed_customer"]))
        {
            $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($_SESSION["subscribed_customer"]);
            $isSubscribed = "";
            if($subscriber->getId())
            {
                $isSubscribed = $subscriber->getData('subscriber_status') == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_SUBSCRIBED;
                if($isSubscribed)
                {
                    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
                    $quoteid = $quote->getId();
                    //$total = $quote->getGrandTotal();
                    $total = $quote->getSubtotal();

                    $discountAmount = number_format(($total - $total / 1.05), 2);
                    if($quoteid)
                    {
                        if($discountAmount > 0)
                        {
                            $total = $quote->getBaseSubtotal();
                            $quote->setSubtotal(0);
                            $quote->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                            $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
                            $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

                            $quote->setGrandTotal(0);
                            $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(0);


                            $canAddItems = $quote->isVirtual() ? ('billing') : ('shipping');
                            foreach($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address)
                            {

                                $address->setSubtotal(0);
                                $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

                                $address->setGrandTotal(0);
                                $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

                                $address->collectTotals();

                                $quote->setSubtotal((float) $quote->getSubtotal() + $address->getSubtotal());
                                $quote->setBaseSubtotal((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getBaseSubtotal());
                                $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount());
                                $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() + $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount());
                                $quote->setGrandTotal((float) $quote->getGrandTotal() + $address->getGrandTotal());
                                $quote->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $quote->getBaseGrandTotal() + $address->getBaseGrandTotal());
                                $quote->save();

                                $quote->setGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                                ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                                ->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                                ->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount)
                                ->save();


                                if($address->getAddressType() == $canAddItems)
                                {
                                    $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getSubtotalWithDiscount() - $discountAmount);
                                    $address->setGrandTotal((float) $address->getGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);
                                    $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount((float) $address->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() - $discountAmount);
                                    $address->setBaseGrandTotal((float) $address->getBaseGrandTotal() - $discountAmount);

                                    // When Mageno Promo Code is used
                                    if($address->getDiscountDescription())
                                    {
                                        $address->setDiscountAmount(($address->getDiscountAmount() - $discountAmount));
                                        //$address->setDiscountAmount($total - $discountAmount);
                                        $address->setDiscountDescription($address->getDiscountDescription());
                                        //$address->setBaseDiscountAmount($total - $discountAmount);
                                        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($address->getBaseDiscountAmount() - $discountAmount));
                                    }
                                    // When Subscribed Customer 5% discount is used
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //$address->setDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
                                        $address->setDiscountAmount($total - $discountAmount);
                                        $address->setDiscountDescription("5% Discounted Subtotal");
                                        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount($total - $discountAmount);
                                        //$address->setBaseDiscountAmount(-($discountAmount));
                                    }

                                    $address->save();
                                }
                            }

                            foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item)
                            {
                                //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
                                $rat = $item->getPriceInclTax() / $total;
                                $ratdisc = $discountAmount * $rat;

                                $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount() + $ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
                                $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount() + $ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked your code, there is nothing wrong with it. The problem should be somewhere else. May be you have rewritten Sales Order model? Any way try to locate it by disabling functionality in your module config file one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution 
 Replace following:

```
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
    $rat = $item->getPriceInclTax() / $total;
    $ratdisc = $discountAmount * $rat;
    $item->setDiscountAmount(($item->getDiscountAmount() + $ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
    $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(($item->getBaseDiscountAmount() + $ratdisc) * $item->getQty())->save();
}
```

with:

```
foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    //We apply discount amount based on the ratio between the GrandTotal and the RowTotal
    //$rat = $item->getPriceInclTax() / $total;
    //$ratdisc = $discountAmount * $rat;

    $item->setDiscountAmount($discount) + $ratdisc) * $item->getQty());
    $item->setBaseDiscountAmount($discount) * $item->getQty())->save();
}
```

//$discount -> you discount amount